# Separate CLLocationManager for location & heading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have noticed in a few books that quite often two instances of CLLocationManager are created, one for location and a separate one for heading. If you wanted a separate delegate for each I could see the point, but all the methods are unique so I can't really think of a reason for doing this. Is there something I am missing, or is it possible to simplify this and use one CCLocationManager for both location and heading?

```
// LOCATION
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[customMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

// HEADING:
headingManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[headingManager setDelegate: self];
[headingManager setHeadingFilter:kCLHeadingFilterNone];
[headingManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this and all my apps have worked absolutely fine - I'd just use the same one for both :)

I can't even begin to think of a reason why you would do this if the delegates were the same!

Comment: It looked a bit mad to me too, but I just wanted to check I was not missing some trick, much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of interest, which books did you see this in; I'm really intrigued :)

Comment: I have found out what it was, the original code came from iPhone Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, but its entirely my doing as the book only shows getting location, heading was left as an exercise for the reader. I added the 2nd CLLocationManager doing that exercise, but later though I was looking at original unmodified code.

Comment: yeah , but if you encounter a failure, how would you know if it was concerning the fetching of the heading direction, or the location?

Comment: I guess it would give you the correct error code to the delegate (i.e. kCLErrorHeadingFailure for heading errors?) The full list is here : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCLErrorLocationUnknown